# Label nodes of directed graph with edge conditions

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Given a directed graph on $n$ nodes. Can we always label the nodes $1,2,\ldots, n$ once each so that for each node, if it is labelled $i$, then:
>
> - If there is no edge $i\rightarrow i+1$, there is also no edge $i\rightarrow n$.
> - If there is no edge $i\rightarrow i+2$, there is also no edge $i\rightarrow n-1$.
> - $\ldots$
> - If there is no edge $i\rightarrow i+\left\lfloor\frac{n-i}{2}\right\rfloor$, there is also no edge $i\rightarrow i + \left\lceil\frac{n-i}{2}\right\rceil + 1$?

This is true trivially for $n = 2$. If $n = 3$, we label an arbitrary node as $1$ and another node with an edge from $1$ as $2$ (if there are no edges from $1$ at all, $2$ can be chosen arbitrarily.) Similarly, if $n = 4$, we label an arbitrary node as $1$, a node with an edge from $1$ as $2$, and then a node with an edge from $2$ as $3$ (again, if there is no edge as some stage, we can choose the next node freely.)

However, this idea does not work for larger $n$ because even when there is an edge from $2$ to $3$, there may not be one from $1$ to $3$.

Comment: The formula in your last bullet point appears different than the rest of the pattern.  It looks to me like it should be "If there is no edge $i \to i + \left\lfloor \frac{n-i}{2}\right\rfloor$, there is no edge $i \to i+\left\lceil\frac{n-i}{2}\right\rceil + 1$".  Can you confirm?  This formula is in line with "counting forward from $i+1$ and backward from $n$, until they meet".

Comment: @EliJohnson That's right.

Comment: Consider the random graph in which orientations of edges are independent and having probability $1/2$ each. Taking $i,k$ up to $n/3$ in the condition "if there is no edge $i\to i+k$, then there is no edge $i\to n-k+1$, we have for each fixed labeling about $n^2/9$ independent events each of which holds only with probability $3/4$, so the chance that one fixed labeling works is about $(3/4)^{n^2/9}$. But there are only $n!$ labelings, so for large $n$ most graphs are bad.